# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I replace text in a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I want to put text into a field that has been autofilled.

The traditional
`When I fill in "ntoheu" with "nthoeu"`
 seems not to work

Iam also using capybara, and i feel that its ability to successfully insert text into fields is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of

> When fill in "<field_name>" with "som text"

<field_name> can be id or name attribute of the input field